# How to open a new page via url and scroll to div at a new page without using hash sign (#)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to open a new page via url and scroll to div at a new page without using `hash sign (#)` ?

This is my code for scroll page to `id="555"` But not work.

To test my code please load page `test.php?xxx=555`

How can i do ?

```
test.php
```

....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var xxx = "<?PHP echo $_GET[xxx]; ?>";
    alert(xxx);

    var offsetHeight = document.getElementById(xxx).offsetHeight;
    var half_offsetHeight = +offsetHeight/2;
    alert(offsetHeight);
    alert(half_offsetHeight);

    var windows_client_height = $(window).height();
    var half_windows_client_height = +windows_client_height/2;
    alert(windows_client_height);
    alert(half_windows_client_height);

    var scroll_to_middle_page = +half_windows_client_height - +half_offsetHeight;
    alert(scroll_to_middle_page);

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+xxx).offset().top-scroll_to_middle_page
    }, 200); 

});
</script>

<html>
<body>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


<div id="555">55555555555</div>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to scroll on document ready to your element via its id

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var xxx = "<?PHP echo $_GET[xxx]; ?>";
   var windowHeight = $( window ).height();

   // This will smoothly during 1000ms scroll to your element in webpage
   // till it not appear at the middle of screen
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: ( $("#"+xxx).offset().top - windowHeight )
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: i have to use `scrollTop: $("#"+xxx).offset().top-scroll_to_middle_page`

Comment: you want to scroll a bit higher then your element ? or you want that your div will appear at the middle of page not at top ?

Comment: I have updated answer